# Usage of StreamingFileSink is throwing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink, amazon-emr

I know this could be my problem, but trying to graple it for a while.
I am trying to run flink in AWS EMR cluster.

My setup is:
Time series event from Kinesis -> flink job -> Save it to S3

```
    DataStream<Event> kinesis =
                env.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer< (this.streamName, new EventSchema(), kinesisConsumerConfig)).name("source");
    final StreamingFileSink<Event> streamingFileSink =
                StreamingFileSink.<Event>forRowFormat(
                        new org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path("s3a://"+ this.bucketName + "/" + this.objectPrefix),
                        new SimpleStringEncoder<>("UTF-8"))
                        .withBucketAssignerAndPolicy(new OrgIdBucketAssigner(), DefaultRollingPolicy.create().build())
                        .build();

DataStream<Event> eventDataStream =  kinesis
                .rebalance()
                .keyBy(createKeySelectorByChoosingOrgIdFromTheEvent())
                .process(new KeyedProcessFunction<String, Event, Event>() {
                    @Override
                    public void processElement(Event value, Context ctx, Collector<DeviceEvent> out) throws Exception {
                        out.collect(value);
                    }
                });
eventDataStream.addSink(streamingFileSink).name("streamingFileSink");
```

From one of the sites, 
https://www.mail-archive.com/user@flink.apache.org/msg25039.html

UPDATE:
I came to know that in order to make StreamingFileSink work, one has to drop a jar `flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.7.1.jar` to `/usr/lib/flink/lib` folder.
My `/usr/lib/flink/lib` folder in EMR master node looks as below

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     9924 Mar 20 01:06 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.15.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42655628 Mar 20 01:06 flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483665 Mar 20 01:06 log4j-1.2.17.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   140172 Mar 20 01:06 flink-python_2.11-1.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 92070994 Mar 20 01:08 flink-dist_2.11-1.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23451686 May  5 23:04 flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.7.1.jar
```

When I try to run the flink job, it throws the below exception in EMR slaves.

```
2019-05-06 01:43:49,589 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - KeyedProcess -> Sink: streamingFileSink (3/4) (31000a186f6ab11f0066556116c669ba) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ErrorResponseHandler
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:553)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:531)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.DefaultS3ClientFactory.newAmazonS3Client(DefaultS3ClientFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.DefaultS3ClientFactory.createS3Client(DefaultS3ClientFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:256)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.AbstractS3FileSystemFactory.create(AbstractS3FileSystemFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:395)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:318)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.<init>(Buckets.java:112)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink$RowFormatBuilder.createBuckets(StreamingFileSink.java:242)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink.initializeState(StreamingFileSink.java:327)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:278)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeState(StreamTask.java:738)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:289)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:704)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can you pls let me know what is the basic thing I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the cause. Although its very very deceptive.
Flink internally uses AWS SDK version `1.11.271`.
The class `S3ErrorResponseHandler` which is causing NoClassDefFoundError...
has the following static variables.

```
public class S3ErrorResponseHandler implements
        HttpResponseHandler<AmazonServiceException> {
    /** Shared logger for profiling information */
    private static final Log log = LogFactory
            .getLog(S3ErrorResponseHandler.class);

    /** Shared factory for creating XML event readers */
    private static final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory
            .newInstance();

    private static enum S3ErrorTags {
        Error, Message, Code, RequestId, HostId
    };
   ....
   ...
```

In AWS SDK `1.11.272`, the initialization of XMLInputFactory has been removed.
That gave me a clue.
I rebuilt flink library by switching to `1.11.272`. Voila it started working.
This still posed me few unanswered questions.
I did thorough debugging within Flink JVM running in EMR.
The classpath clearly has `flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.7.1.jar`. I wrote a code to read that jar and print all its entries and I did see `S3ErrorResponseHandler`.
In my flink operator, I could initialize as below -

```
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
```

The classloader clearly had reference to jre libs.
Yet, flink was unable to initialize this specific class. I wonder why!! Is it because of how Flink deals with operators!!!
Flink underneath serializes the operators and transmits to slave nodes. In slave nodes, the operators are deserialized, initialized and run as a task.
Between those vaarious phases, the Flink classloader somehow didnt have access to default implementation of XMLInputFactory from JRE. Thats very wierd!!! Also I wish JRE is more specific about which static variable it could not initialize when loading the class.
Should I call this as a bug in Flink?
No one has reported this error in AWS EMR when using Flink?

Also noted that flink relase 1.7.1 has a bug with StreamingFlineSink. If your EMR cluster has 2 mounts, it tries do a read/write operation on both causing it to fail.
It was resolved in 1.8.0 and above. However AWS EMR still uses 1.7.1 release by default. So pls ensure you put 1.8.0 libraries under /usr/lib/flink/lib

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that pops out as looking wrong is that you are mixing together JARs from different flink releases. These are from Flink 1.7.1

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42655628 Mar 20 01:06 flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   140172 Mar 20 01:06 flink-python_2.11-1.7.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 92070994 Mar 20 01:08 flink-dist_2.11-1.7.1.jar
```

while this one is from Flink 1.8.0

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23451686 May  5 23:04 flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.8.0.jar
```

This won't work; pick one release or the other. Note that 1.7.2 is the latest bug fix release in the 1.7 series.

I also recommend you read this section of the docmentation: [Streaming File Sink: Important Considerations for S3](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html#important-considerations-for-s3).

Comment: I did add 1.7.1 release jar as well. But same result.

Comment: I also looked at the flink documentation link you sent.
Initially when using streaming file sink I was using `s3://` as path prefix.
But after seeing the documentation, I decided to use `s3a://`.

Comment: When I look into the internals of flink libraries, for streaming file sink to work, it needs recoverable writer.
When flink session is started, all factory implementations are loaded, which ultimately paves the way for recoverable writer.
The factory implementation that I am interested is `org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.FlinkS3FileSystem` which can inject `S3RecoverableWriter`.
The only way I could all these is by putting this library in that `/usr/lib/flink/lib` folder. I wonder, how I will all these things will work in CD world. But thats a seperate discussion.

Comment: If anyone has achieved success using `StreamingFileSink` in AWS EMR, pls let me know what I am missing. The "NoClassDefFoundError" looks like childish. The jar `flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.8.0.jar` does have `org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.S3ErrorResponseHandler`.
Also looked at all static variables in that class, it should not have a problem initializing it.

Comment: Few other details, its worth sharing.
I am using latest EMR release 'emr-5.23.0'.
I have one master node and 4 slave nodes in my EMR cluster setup.

Comment: Updated the description to reflect the usage of 1.7.1 flink libraries